# Android - Need help cropping instead of resizing an imageview extending beyond parent layout

Tags: android

I have a relative layout with some ImageViews that sometimes extend beyond the layout's boundaries.
When this happens the ImageViews get resized so they become smaller instead of extend out of bounds. I want them to display normally and just get cropped.

I think there is some kind of boolean to do that, but I can't find it in the API. 
I thought it might be clipChildren under ViewGroups, but setting that to false or true seems to do nothing. Anyone help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late but have you tried this code in your xml?

```
   <ImageView
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
 android:id="@+id/imageView"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

The key is in scaleType. It keeps the aspect ratio of your image cropping it to the bounds of layout.